# What does constructor return?

Tags: java, constructor

In Java, `Constructor` returns anything or not?
Because it does not contain any return type.
And also it does not contains `void`, too.

Comment: It's not a regular method, though seen from the code, in combination with `new`, it acts as if it returns the object it just constructed.

Comment: Simply `Nothing`. First docs, then google then SO.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is not a regular method. you missed the point. `Constructor` `return` an `object` (instance) of that `class`. But that is not like what method does in `Java`.